# How to hide tab icons in landscape mode?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-tabactivity

Tabs take too much height when in landscape mode, I think it will be much better if I can hide icons.

[image: landscape mode]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following useful in such a situation:

```
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
```

The height of 30 dp makes it just tall enough for the text (cutting off the icon) and the gravity set to bottom makes sure all of the text is visible (otherwise you end up with a space on the bottom and the bottom half of the text above it).